# Old English forms of address

Tags: old-english, old-norse

I am doing some research on Anglo-Saxon England and wondering if there are any particular forms of address in Old English that are a) roughly equivalent to Mr. Mrs. Ms., etc. in terms of formality, b) or was it an entirely other mode of addressing strangers and/or people in a more formal environment (i.e. use of titles, names, etc.)?

And, how similar would this be from how addresses are dealt with in Old Norse?

Answer (score 2):

In Anglo-Saxon [***lēof***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leof) 'beloved, dear' was used in a similar manner, though it was not as formal. e.g. "[*lēofa Bēowulf*](http://www.heorot.dk/beowulf-rede-text.html)" 'dear Beowulf', "[*lēof ealdormann*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ve_8AwAAQBAJ&pg=PA241&lpg=PA241&dq=leof%20form%20of%20address%20anglo%20saxon&source=bl&ots=C32PrFcaIC&sig=H4Wt35DYkZqABj15XBm84AKIrds&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjaxtiMxMjXAhUJr1QKHfDIBQQQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=leof%20&f=false)" 'Mister Alderman'.

In Old Norse some sources have [***herra***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=exact&lookup=herra&lang=non) 'venerable' with a usage similar to "master, lord".